# solr query returns inproper results for same query

Tags: search, solr, apache-zookeeper, solrcloud

I am using solr 4.3.0 in production with zookeeper 3.4.5 on windows and solr 4.0.0 on Linux box in local environment. I have implemented solr search and solr index update architectures and they seems to be working fine on local and production too.But some time on production when i update the index document and then query to retrieve the updated document it gives weird behavior, as some times it return correct updated document while sometime returns old document. Initially my thought was i am using JMS for document update and that can be a problem but this behavior is random and non reproducible on local. So i thought there must be some issue with NRT search in solr version 4.3.0.

Any help would be very help full.

Answer (score 0):

Hi Can you please check if it is not some cache issue.

Comment: But as per my knowledge,document cache and query result cache both gets updated on any change in the document being cached by either cache. More over caches are extensively used by many productions environments by various implementers, so i did not suspect the caches.And by the way i am not using caches so badly, just the default settings only